transfomers runtimeError `No module named 'keras.__internal__`
I have these installed:
keras                         3.5.0
tensorflow                    2.17.0
tensorflow-intel              2.17.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.31.0
torch                         2.2.2

And transformers results an error:
from transformers import pipeline
pipeline("text-classification")

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_tf_distilbert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'keras.__internal__


Just on a whim, you don't have a file called keras.py in your project, do you?

@TimRoberts I forgot how I solved the problem in the end, perhaps updated keras.
